# Assert multiple change expectations within a single lambda request

Tags: rspec2

I have a test like that:

```
lambda { post("/api/users", parameters) }.should change(User,:count).by(1)
lambda { post("/api/users", parameters) }.should_not change(ActionMailer::Base, :deliveries)
```

But I want to do it like that:

```
lambda { post("/api/users", parameters) }.should change(User,:count).by(1).and_not change(ActionMailer::Base, :deliveries)
```

Is it possible to do it without the need of two post calls?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found a solution to test it.

```
lambda{
  lambda { post("/api/users", params) }.should change(User,:count).by(1)
}.should change(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries, :count).by(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my tests I am very strict: I want each test to test only a single thing. So I would always choose the first form, not the second.

Secondly I am not sure it is technically possible. The `.should` expects a block, which is executed before and after the lambda. Anyway, to my knowledge currently rspec does not support this (and imho with good reason).

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this issue when migrating some `request` tests over to `feature` test format for Capybara 2.1, and switching the testing syntax there from `should`-based to `expect`-based.  To use the original question as the example, I had code like:

```
subject { -> { post("/api/users", parameters) } }
it { should change(User,:count).by(1) }
it { should_not change(ActionMailer::Base, :deliveries) }
```

Bringing this over to `expect` syntax in a `scenario` test presented some issues and yielded this kind of (working) clunkiness (sorry, not a big fan of explicitly nested `lambda`s/`expect`s):

```
expect(-> { expect(post("/api/users", parameters)).to change(User,:count).by(1) }
).to_not change(ActionMailer::Base, :deliveries)
```

There are some great solutions to this issue in [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12260534/567863) which I tried and succeeded with, but what I ended up doing was simply follow the original format somewhat and split out each statement into its own `scenario`; something like:

```
feature "Add users via API" do
  given(:posting_parameters_to_api) { -> { post("/api/users", parameters) } }

  scenario "foo" do
    expect(posting_parameters_to_api).to change(User,:count).by(1)
  end

  scenario "bar" do
    expect(posting_parameters_to_api).to_not change(ActionMailer::Base, 
                                                    :deliveries)
  end
end
```

More verbose than the original `request` spec, but essentially working in the same way.  Implementation will likely come down to personal taste.