# Using implicit `subject` with `expect` in RSpec-2.11

Tags: ruby, syntax, rspec, rspec2

With the new `expect` syntax in rspec-2.11, how is it possible to use the implicit `subject`? Is there a better way than explicitly referencing `subject`, like below?

```
describe User do
  it 'is valid' do
    expect(subject).to be_valid    # <<< can `subject` be implicit?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you configure RSpec to disable the `should` syntax, you can still use the old one-liner syntax, since that doesn't involve `should` being added to every object:

```
describe User do
  it { should be_valid }
end
```

We [briefly discussed](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/pull/119#issuecomment-4311115) an alternate one-liner syntax, but decided against it since it wasn't needed and we felt like it might add confusion.  You can, however, easily add this yourself if you prefer how it reads:

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.alias_example_to :expect_it
end

RSpec::Core::MemoizedHelpers.module_eval do
  alias to should
  alias to_not should_not
end
```

With this in place, you could write this as:

```
describe User do
  expect_it { to be_valid }
end
```

Comment: As of RSpec 2.13.0 the module `RSpec::Core::Subject::ExampleMethods` no longer exists. Instead use `RSpec::Core::MemoizedHelpers`

Comment: @Myron I just asked a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682147/rspec-expect-syntax-and-idiomatic-attribute-spec/16682568?noredirect=1#16682568) though I was explicitly concerned with one-line blocks. I'm just curious:  is there any talk of eventually deprecating the old one-liner syntax or requiring any additional configuration (aside from what you mention above) to use it?

Comment: There is no old one-liner syntax.  The "old" one-liner syntax is still the current one-liner syntax and we have no plans to deprecate it.

Comment: I read the brief discussion about `expect_it` that you guys had, but I didn't see any real objection to it as a complement to what you ended up with except for the fear that you'd get a lot of questions about why `expect {...}` doesn't work. I hope you'll reconsider it as a standard feature of an upcoming release.  I think the presence of "it" in `expect_it` should be enough to avoid confusion (i.e. to get folks to think of it as an `it` alternative rather than an `expect` alternative).

Comment: RSpec 2.99 3.0.0.beta2 introduce is_expected. You can use it like this: it { is_expected.to be_valid }. is_expected is substitude for expect(subject).

Answer (score 17):

With Rspec 3.0 you can use `is_expected` as described [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/subject/one-liner-syntax).

```
describe Array do
  describe "when first created" do
    # Rather than:
    # it "should be empty" do
    #   subject.should be_empty
    # end

    it { should be_empty }
    # or
    it { is_expected.to be_empty }
  end
end
```

Comment: This question was for Rspec 2.11, not Rspec 3 (which is still Beta as of this post)

Answer (score 12):

One could use the new named subject syntax, although it's not implicit.

```
describe User do
  subject(:author) { User.new }

  it 'is valid' do
    expect(author).to be_valid
  end
end
```

Comment: You could define the subject as `:it` and then use `expect(it).to be_valid`

Comment: This is inelegant, though, since you're using three lines to express what could be expressed in one line with the old one-liner `should` syntax, or with custom configuration as explained by Myron above.