# RSpec 'Expect' Syntax and Idiomatic attribute spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This should have an easy answer but I'm struggling to find it (have checked RSpec documentation, EverydayRails Testing with RSpec, Google results). In my model specs I like to include basic attribute specs as follows:

```
describe Foo do
  describe "basic attributes" do
    before { @foo = create(:foo) }
    subject { @foo }

    it { should be_valid }
    it { should respond_to(:color) }
    it { should respond_to(:height) }
    it { should respond_to(:some_other_attribute) }
    it { should respond_to(:you_get_the_idea) }
    ...
```

I like these specs because if there is some kind of error within my factory and/or model these specs help me pinpoint it quickly.

I've incorporated the `expect` syntax into all other specs and I like how it reads, but how to use it here? One option might be

```
expect(@foo).to respond_to(:color)
```

And another might be

```
expect(it).to respond_to(:color)
```

The former involves duplication that is avoided with the `should` syntax, but the latter looks strange to me (which could just be me).

I realize this question is more about style than functionality*, but we Ruby developers are conscientious about style, and I want to adhere to standard practices and have readable, idiomatic code. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE:  Neither of my proposed options actually work, by the way. They both throw `undefined method 'expect'` errors. Now I'm really confused!

Having thought about the error, I realize it's because the `should` specs above are within one-line block. The confusion, then, is how can I write a single-line block with the expect syntax? In light of this update, the question is very much about functionality and I'll be excited to hear others' thoughts.

4/2015 UPDATE

`rspec > 3.0` has added yet another way of handling these, and it sounds like `rspec ~> 4.0` will do away with the `should` syntax. Per Myron Masters:

> Some users have expressed confusion about how this should relates to the expect syntax and if you can continue using it. It will continue to be available in RSpec 3 (again, regardless of your syntax configuration), but we've also added an alternate API that is a bit more consistent with the expect syntax:

```
describe Post do
  it { is_expected.to allow_mass_assignment_of(:title) }
end
```

> is_expected is defined very simply as expect(subject) and also supports negative expectations via is_expected.not_to matcher.
>   [...]
>   In RSpec 3, we've kept the should syntax, and it is available by default, but you will get a deprecation warning if you use it without explicitly enabling it. This will pave the way for it being disabled by default (or potentially extracted into a seperate gem) in RSpec 4, while minimizing confusion for newcomers coming to RSpec via an old tutorial.

Comment: Can you share one of your specs which incorporated the `expect` syntax?

Comment: These are pretty basic and are in the RSpec docs as well as in other sources. Here's a great blog post about the syntax:  http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax. My examples essentially look like this, but they're in blocks (i.e. `it "does something" do` )...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Myron Marston, one of the core RSpec committers, explains [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12266147/126042) that you should still use

```
it { should be_cool }
```

If you've disabled the `should` syntax, he offers a solution to alias `expect_it` to `it`:

> ```
> RSpec.configure do |c|
>   c.alias_example_to :expect_it
> end
>
> RSpec::Core::MemoizedHelpers.module_eval do
>   alias to should
>   alias to_not should_not
> end
> ```
>
> With this in place, you could write this as:
>
> ```
> describe User do
>   expect_it { to be_valid }
> end
> ```

Comment: Wow, great find on that question! Also, I linked Myron's blog post in a comment above, so that's funny that you found his answer to a very similar question. I wonder if the one-liner `should` will be deprecated at some point. 

I haven't configured RSpec to disable the `should` syntax so I suppose I'll still use it in this case. Thank you!

Comment: Just to be clear: even if you have configured things to disable the `should` syntax, the one liner `it { should matcher }` syntax still works: disabling the `should` syntax is about not monkey patching all objects with should but `ExampleGroup#should` still works as it requieres no monkey patches.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a correct answer to this question, but I've been recently rewriting my test suites to move away from `should` and use the `expect` syntax exclusively, so I'll throw my two cents in.  I decided to re-write pretty much because [Myron Marston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29262/myron-marston), the RSpec lead maintainer, [wrote](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax):

> In the future, we plan to change the defaults so that only expect is available unless you explicitly enable should. We may do this as soon as RSpec 3.0, but we want to give users plenty of time to get acquianted with it.

He also [commented](http://branch.com/b/which-rspec-syntax-do-you-prefer):

> We have no plans to ever remove "should"...but expect has fewer gotchas, and is the syntax I would recommend for new projects.

I do agree with [Mark Rushakoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126042/mark-rushakoff)'s answer as well, but personally I don't want to have to create those aliases just to keep a single `it`-block style syntax.  So, using your example, where originally I wrote a model spec like your example in this form:

```
describe Foo do
  let(:foo) { create(:foo) }
  subject { foo }
  describe "model attributes" do
    it { should be_valid }
    it { should respond_to(:color) }
    it { should respond_to(:height) }
    it { should respond_to(:some_other_attribute) }
    it { should respond_to(:you_get_the_idea) }
  end
  # ...
end
```

I now would tend to write it like:

```
describe Foo do
  let(:foo) { create(:foo) }
  specify "model attributes" do
    expect(foo).to be_valid
    expect(foo).to respond_to(:color)
    expect(foo).to respond_to(:height)
    expect(foo).to respond_to(:some_other_attribute)
    expect(foo).to respond_to(:you_get_the_idea)
  end
  # ...
end
```

My opinion is that referencing `foo` directly in `expect(foo).to respond_to(:color)` is as much "duplication" as referencing a `subject` indirectly using `it`, so I'm not too phased about it, and I'm warming to the way that `expect` specs generally read.  But, ultimately I think this comes down to just being an issue of preferred writing style.

Comment: You're right in that "duplication" isn't really a big deal, though for longer model names using 'it' saves a lot of characters, especially if there are many attributes. Thanks for a thoughtful answer!

Comment: I see where you're coming from and that's fair enough.  On a similar note, I like to keep my lines within 80 characters across, and if you do have a long test line, while an `it` block can allow multiple lines by changing the `{`...`}` to `do ... end`, an `expect` statement over multiple lines ends up looking like `expect(foo).to \ be_valid` with `be_valid` on the next line.  This can look a bit awkward at first, but I've gotten used to it; again, just personal preference.

Comment: I've been writing multi-line `expect` specs as follows:

`expect { \
some.really.long.code  \
}.to be_valid`

which I assumed was idiomatic, but maybe was mistaken??

Comment: I don't think you're mistaken as there is an implicit block in `expect(foo)` that you can multi-line explicitly as you have.  I simply just prefer to have the `expect(some.really.long.code).to` statement to all be on the same line for my own subjective ideas on readability :-)

Comment: Is "create" coming from FactoryGirl?

Comment: @Matt - yes, `create` is coming from Factory Girl. I modified the syntax in `spec_helper.rb` as explained here:  https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md.

Comment: @aceofbassgreg - Thanks.  All- I like this solution, but is there an efficient way to then 'rspec -f doc' such that model attributes are displayed under the specify text? Essentially I'm trying to document and test in one swell-foop.