# How do I convert from "should" to "expect" convention?

Tags: ruby, rspec, cancan

I've just started working with rspec, and I use `expect` instead of `should` convention.

How can I transform this test example from CanCan from `should` to `expect`?:

```
require "cancan/matchers"
# ...
describe "User" do
  describe "abilities" do
    subject { ability }
    let(:ability){ Ability.new(user) }
    let(:user){ nil }

    context "when is an account manager" do
      let(:user){ Factory(:accounts_manager) }

      it{ should be_able_to(:manage, Account.new) }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't have to replace this instance of `should`, per [Using implicit `subject` with `expect` in RSpec-2.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260534/using-implicit-subject-with-expect-in-rspec-2-11), but if you want to, you'd have to give up the one-liner approach and use:

```
it "should be able to manage a new account" do
  expect(ability).to be_able_to(:manage, Account.new)
end
```

in place of the current `it` clause.  As an aside, there looks to be some extraneous code in this test.