# shoulda-matchers RSpec expect syntax

Tags: rspec, shoulda

What is the correct format for using [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) and RSpec's new [expect syntax](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax)?

Comment: Sorry I meant shoulda

Comment: Regarding the vote-to-close based on this being primarily opinion based, I would argue that this particular instance of asking if something is a "good idea" is an exception because there is a fact-based explanation that the concern is a non-issue.

Comment: edited the quesrion detail to make it be appropriate for SO.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

While one could certainly use the shoulda-matchers with the new expect syntax as follows:

```
it 'should validate presence of :email' do
  expect(subject).to validate_presence_of :email
end
```

or the more concise but less readable:

```
it { expect(subject).to validate_presence_of :email }
```

the one-liner `should` format these matchers are typically used with is explicitly supported in 2.14 even when `config.syntax == :expect`. **When `should` is being used with an implicit subject as in:**

```
describe User
  it { should validate_presence_of :email }
end
```

**it does not rely on the monkey patching of `Kernel` that `should` otherwise depends on.**

This is covered in https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/Should.md. In fact, that documentation even uses the above `shoulda` matcher example to illustrate this exception.

See also [Using implicit `subject` with `expect` in RSpec-2.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260534/using-implicit-subject-with-expect-in-rspec-2-11), which discusses a configuration option which lets you use as an alternative to `it`.

```
expect_it { to validate_presence_of :email }
```

Update: As of RSpec 3.0 (beta2), you will also be able to use:

```
it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of :email }
```

Comment: The first block would also be surrounded by the `desribe User`, right?  As it it looks like a omparison of 3 lines to 3 different lines, but isn't quite that.  If so might want to add that for clarity in first code block.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Yes, it would. Agreed. Thanks for pointing this out. Answer updated.

Comment: Anyone have any idea what the downvote is for? Is it related to the close votes for this being "primarily opinion based"?

Comment: It's too bad that you need the it block. I always liked shoulda matches because of their concise syntax.

Comment: Actually, you _don't_ need the block. That was what I intended as the essence of my answer. The one-liner `should` form is completely acceptable and fully accepted/supported by the latest convention. But you did give me an idea. What if RSpec introduced `expect_it` as an alias for `expect(subject)`?

Answer (score 0):

I'll suplement the answer of @peter-alfvin. In case you test the model and its migration themselves with `shoulda-matchers` you can't use `:expect` outside of `it` block, so can't write:

```
RSpec.describe ModelName, type: :model do
   expect(subject).to belong_to(:user)
end
```

And you will get the expection:

```
`expect` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).
```

but correct version is:

```
RSpec.describe ModelName, type: :model do
   it { expect(subject).to belong_to(:user) }
end
```