# RSpec test for pundit using expect syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, pundit

I'm trying to convert the following spec to new expect syntax, could anyone help?

```
describe PostPolicy do
  subject { PostPolicy }

  permissions :create? do
    it "denies access if post is published" do
      should_not permit(User.new(:admin => false), Post.new(:published => true))
    end

    it "grants access if post is published and user is an admin" do
      should permit(User.new(:admin => true), Post.new(:published => true))
    end

    it "grants access if post is unpublished" do
      should permit(User.new(:admin => false), Post.new(:published => false))
    end
  end
end
```

I tried that, but it didn't work because `permit()` returns a matcher -- `RSpec::Matchers::DSL::Matcher`:

```
specify { expect(permit(@user, @post)).to be_true }
```

Comment: Don't know. Upvote if you find it useful :)

Comment: I will am having the same trouble with testing policy_scope testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to invoke the `subject` explicitly since the implicit receiver only works for `should`. More information [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/subject/implicit-receiver) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260534/using-implicit-subject-with-expect-in-rspec-2-11).

In your example, this should work:

```
describe PostPolicy do
  subject { PostPolicy }

  permissions :create? do
    it "denies access if post is published" do
      expect(subject).not_to permit(User.new(:admin => false), Post.new(:published => true))
    end

    it "grants access if post is published and user is an admin" do
      expect(subject).not_to permit(User.new(:admin => true), Post.new(:published => true))
    end

    it "grants access if post is unpublished" do
      expect(subject).not_to permit(User.new(:admin => false), Post.new(:published => false))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, you are almost right, but specifying subject is required, it fails otherwise with `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the implicit subject syntax.

```
describe PostPolicy do
  subject { PostPolicy }

  permission :create? do
    it { is_expected.not_to permit(User.new(admin: false), Post.new(published: true)) }
  end
end
```

`is_expected` simply calls `expect(subject)`. It makes for a little more convenient one liners.